# Using CNN's in Unity via Tensorflow and TensorFlowSharp

Tags: unity, c#, python

I have a project that tracks hands made in python, shown here: https://github.com/timctho/convolutional-pose-machines-tensorflow

I want to effectively import this into Unity. I have generates the .bytes file from the model, but have no idea how to do anything further than this. If anyone has worked with ML-Agents or TensorflowSharp in Unity and/or would be willing to have a look, this would be great. The image-processing stuff would be done probably in a C# file beforehand, I just want to know how to run the network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to create a frozen graph (with the extension .pb) and use TensorFlowSharp so this no interaction with any Python. For example, my code looks like this:

```
        TFGraph graph = new TFGraph();
        graph.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/frozen_model.pb"));

        TFTensor input = ImageUtil.CreateTensorFromImageFile("C:/Users/Lopes/Desktop/longhand.jpg", TFDataType.Float);

        float[][][][] outfloats;

        using (TFSession sess = new TFSession(graph))
        {
            var runner = sess.GetRunner();
            runner.AddInput(graph[input_tensorname][0], input);

            runner.Fetch(graph[output_tensorname][0]);
            var output = runner.Run();
            outfloats = (float[][][][])output[0].GetValue();
        }
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar conundrum.

Comment: Although the actual process of analysing the data is proving to be a bit of a challenge!